# Array passing between classes, gone?

Tags: iphone

Hey guys . i have two classes, SelectionScreenTable & GraphView.

In the SelectionScreenTable class .h, i declared a NSMutableArray called usagedatas

```
    NSMutableArray *usagedatas;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *usagedatas;
```

In the SelectionScreenTable class.m i remembered to @synthesize.
Later on, while processing my methods, i did a

```
NSLog(@"usagedatas count:%i",usagedatas.count);
```

to check whether it has value and it returned 1. so yeah its good up to this point.

And in the -(void) dealloc , i remembered to released it .

```
[usagedatas release];
```

So now comes ME trying to use it in another class.

In GraphView.m i imported the "SelectionScreenTable.h". 
in the -(void)viewDidLoad i did

```
SelectionScreenTable *UD = [SelectionScreenTable alloc];

 NSLog(@"GraphView UD.usagedataas.count =  :%i",UD.usagedatas.count);
```

it returned 0.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Forgot to mention i tried doing 
SelectionScreenTable *UD = [[SelectionScreenTable alloc]init];
not working too

Comment: On this code you are showing, you are only creating a property as a pointer to an array. Are you actually setting that property to something? Otherwise, it will be `nil`, and the `count` message will return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, i solved it by creating the array in the AppDelegate instead. then in SelectionScreenTable i get the array from the AppDelegate and edit it. 
Then in GraphView i just call the array from the AppDelegate and it returns a value.